# Does the automatic backup backup itself?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

In Ubuntu I have noticed that there is an automatic backup feature, and by default it backs up the home folder, but the folder where it backs it up to is also in the home folder, so

- does it also backup its own back, and might this not cause an
  infinite loop of backing up the same folder, and then having the new
  contents in the folder (the backup of itself) and then deciding to
  backup again?
- Even if there is no loop as such, does it still backup itself?
- And does that not make backups much larger? Should I then add the
  backup folder to the ignore list, or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deja Dup (the name of the default backup program in Ubuntu) will ignore its own backup folder, where it keeps the backup files. There should be no looping.

It does this automatically, you don't need to add it to your list of folders to ignore during a backup.